# String replace using huge heap space

Tags: java

I am doing a xml parsing and doing some string `replaceAll` which is using a huge amount of memory space as shown in the below image.

Code goes like:

```
private final String getText() {
  // special handling for apostrophe encoding
  // site will expect both &#39; , &apos; and %27.
  // change %27 or &#39;or &apos; to '
  return _text.toString().trim().replaceAll("&apos;", "'")
            .replaceAll("&#39;", "'").replaceAll("%27", "'");
}
```

The `getText()` method is frequently call from `endElement()` method of SAXParser.

Can anyone suggest how do change this functionality which will use lesser heap space

![trace][1]

Comment: are you dealing with huge text nodes in your xml?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) uses [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and you don't need them plus they are overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions for simple string replacement like this is too expensive.
I would simply build a StringBuilder instance like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (not end of _text) {
   find next '&'
   if the next substring is in (&apos; &#39;) etc.
     append the prev portion of _text to sb
     append replacement char
     set the beginning of the chunk to the next char
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `_text` is already a `StringBuffer` you can use `indexOf(String str)` and `replace(int start, int end, String str)`. This way you will not create temporary `String` objects at all.

Using a function like:

```
private void replace(StringBuffer buff,String toReplace,String replaceTo){
 int start;
 while ((start=buff.indexOf(toReplace))>=0)
   buff.replace(start,start+toReplace.length(),replaceTo);
}
```

and call the function in you `getText()`, for each combination, like:

```
String replaceTo=",";
replace(_text,"&apos;",replaceTo);
replace(_text,"&#39;",replaceTo);
replace(_text,"%27",replaceTo);
return _text.toString();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all 3 replacements in one go as

```
text.replaceAll("(&apos;|&39;|%27)", "'");
```

it is up to 3 times more efficient than 3 consecutive replacement, since each replace may create a new String

Answer (score 1):

Your replaceAll method is called on a `String`, which is immutable. Because of that, a whole new string has to be created everytime you modify it (3 times in this case). If you use a `StringBuilder` instead, your string will be mutable, and doesn't need to be allocated again everytime you replace something.

By the way, there's no "replace" like you need in StringBuilders, so you'll have to use `indexOf` repeatedly to find your offending string, and `replace` on the findings. trim() is there.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting your text in SAX it must come from here

```
characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
```

you have to save these args in fields, and on endElement() you can do your replacement as

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = start; i < length; i++) {
               // %27
        if (ch[i] == '%' && length - i > 2 && ch[i + 1] == '2' && ch[i + 2] == '7') {
                         sb.append('\'');
            i += 2;
                // &apos;
                } else if (
                   ...
                // &#39;
                } else if (
                   ...
        } else {
            sb.append(ch[i]);
        }
    }
    String res = sb.toString();
```

the code is long but very efficient, you can also add trimming